# can't acces method of parent controller from child controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My html

```
<section class="localsContainer" ng-controller="LocalsCtrl">
    <h3>Lokale</h3>
    <div class="placesProgress"></div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="city in cities">
            <p ng-show="city.LocalCount > 0" ng-click="getLocals(city.Id)">{{city.Name}}</p>
            <ul ng-show="activeCityLeft === city.Id">
                <li ng-repeat="local in locals[city.Id]">
                    <p>{{local.Name}} ng-click="getDetails()"</p>   
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li ng-if="cities.length == 0">
            <strong>Nie znaleziono</strong>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

and js

```
angular.module('sandboxApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, API) {
      API.newRequest('getCitiesList').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.cities = data.data;
      });
      $scope.getDetails = function () {
          console.log("test")
      };
  })
  .controller('LocalsCtrl', function ($scope, API) {
      $scope.locals = {};

      $scope.getLocals = function (cityid) {
          $scope.activeCityLeft = cityid;
          API.newRequest('getLocalList', { params: { 'city_id': cityid.toString() }, cache: true }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.locals[cityid] = data.data;
          });
      };
  })
```

If i understand correctly i should be able to invoke 'getDetails' method anywhere because it is defined on main controller, even from elements which got their won controllers but are nested within element attached to main controller. but it does'nt work, when i click on element which should invoke getDetails, instead it displays 'ng-click="getDetails()' as html text.

Comment: Attributes need to be on an element, e.g. `<p ng-click="getDetails()">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ng-click` is defined wrong - you defined it as text inside a `<p>` element:

```
<p>{{local.Name}} ng-click="getDetails()"</p>
```

You should define it as an attribute since it is a directive:

```
<p ng-click="getDetails()">{{local.Name}}</p>
```

Comment: @user3561092 Happens all the time... glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

use ng-click as attribute since it is directive and directives(attribute) are used like attributes, you are displaying it as text

[see refrence](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) for ng-click

```
 <p ng-click="getDetails()">{{local.Name}} </p>
```